# aliasing basic types and constants in C#

Tags: c#

We have a C++ code that defines a unified naming convention (majorly for multiplatform reasons).
For example:

`#define FOO_UINT32 unsigned long`
and
`#define FOO_TRUE true`

now, we want to port some of this code to C#.
For the first define in the example I figured out that I need:

`using FOO_UINT32 = System.UInt32;`

The question is? How do I do the second one?

Comment: I don't think that's how you use `using`s, or how you port C++ to C#.

Comment: @BoltClock not entirely accurate, `using` is also used when aliasing types / namespaces.  As for the port, I'd run a mile if I saw C# code aliasing basic types.

Comment: @Bolt You can use `using` for that, for the current file. Typically used to resolve ambiguity or to reduce namespace clutter (when you can't add a normal using clause.)

Comment: Ah, cripes - forgetting something so obvious in a day.

Comment: The big question to me is why would you want to do that? The reasons for doing it in C++ does not apply to C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `true` is not a type, you can't utilize a `using` directive to alias it. You can create a `static` class with a `const` member to get a similar result:

```
public static class PortConstants
{
    public const bool FOO_TRUE = true;
}
```

Then you can say `bool x = PortConstants.FOO_TRUE;`. I'd recommend just using `true`, though.

You may also want to drop the `using` alias for `UInt32` as well, since the CLR type won't be changing, and is consistent across platforms for which a CLR implementation is available.

Comment: well, you got me convinced that there is no point in aliasing the basic types. My original thought was to make the code as much similar as possible to the C++, nevertheless - good answer!

Comment: @Boaz if you want to make the code as similar as possible, there might be a more relevant migration path into the managed world via C++.NET.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to define a constant, that is the closest you get.

```
public const bool FOO_TRUE = true;
```

Also note that the `using` "trick" to handle the type alias will be for the file it is defined in *only*.

Now, the bigger question is, are you porting or converting? By porting I mean that you want to keep the ability to try to merge in updates to the original sourcebase into the port.

With a conversion you're basically reimplementing functionality.

If you're doing the latter, you should dispense with these "tricks" altogether and pick a C#/.NET way of doing it instead.

Note that if you use `UInt32` in your code, this type will never change to be 16-bit or 64-bit depending on platform, it will always be 32-bit and unsigned. As such, the need for such alias types to handle platform inconsistencies is greatly reduced in .NET and C# so my advice would be to just dispense with that type alias altogether and use `UInt32` instead.

The same goes for `FOO_TRUE`, `true` will always be a bool type, regardless of platform.

The best thing for forward-going code is to use the idioms of the platform you're programming on.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I advise not doing this at all... you will be safe using `System.UInt32` in the C# code in place of `FOO_INT32`.

With the `true` option, it is a value so cannot be aliased.  You'd need to make a constant, but again, don't unless it's a good constant in the sense of:

```
public class Constants
{
    public const double PI = 3.14; // good use of constants, accuracy of PI could improve in future.
    public const bool FOO_TRUE = true; // bad use of constants, or at the very least, bad naming
}
```

Comment: CURRENTLY_EMPLOYED, how is this good use of a constant if it "could change in the system." Any calling assemblies etc. will get this baked into them. The second one sounds like a much better use of constants to me. What am I missing?

Comment: @Steven you are missing the concept that a constant representing true will never actually change.  Constants are enforced at compile-time from change at runtime, but it's perfectly valid to change the value at compile-time.  If true ever became false, you'd get code with `FOO_TRUE` everywhere when it's false... it's quite conceivable for `CURRENTLY_EMPLOYED` to be false.  The affect this has on the system, on the other hand, is anyone's guess.  In all honesty, I've never seen a constant need to change anyway, but I've thankfully never seen a constant covering a baked in value `true`.

Comment: @Steven that said, if `true` ever did become `false` I'd be up the creek and Boaz would be laughing :-)

Comment: Well if currently_employed ever changed, it woud mean recompiling every singly assembly that referenced it. You roll out patches, you have to roll out everything. FOO_TRUE sounds much less likely to suddenly become false to me. So IMO is a move valid use of a constant.

Comment: @Steven valid yes, the compiler is not going to smack you.  Pointless?  Well, yes, `true` will always be `true`.  In my rather pants example, `CURRENTLY_EMPLOYED` could be false.  If you didn't use a constant, you'd trawl the code for everywhere you used this pseudo-constant value for the state of employment and turn it false.  If you use the constant, you change one value and the other references follow.  As for recompiling, you state the obvious - you are using `const` after all.

Comment: @Steven constant doesn't necessarily mean once defined, locked forever.  I suppose a better example might be a constant for `Pi`.  In future, you might want to improve the accuracy of `Pi`.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm just bit.....confused by the "currently". This makes it sound like it could change at any moment. Perhaps your employment status is just so very secure you don't ever have to worry about that :-)

Comment: @Steven yeah it's coming to the boundary of hard-coded versus configuration.  In a "likely to change" scenario, I'd configure.  In a "could possibly change" scenario, constants will likely work.  Apologies if this degenerated a little, I was trying to stress the point that wrapping a baked-in value with a constant is a bit of an abuse of constants, but my supporting example wasn't great either.

Answer (score 0):

Static class with consts maybe

```
public static class Constants
{
   public const bool FOO_TRUE = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[C# does provide a #define directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), however

> The #define directive cannot be used to declare constant values as is
>   typically done in C and C++. Constants in C# are best defined as
>   static members of a class or struct. If you have several such
>   constants, consider creating a separate "Constants" class to hold
>   them.

You are better off creating a static class and defining them like so:

```
public const bool FOO_TRUE = true;
```

I would ask though, why do you want to do this?

Comment: or even better of not doing it at all, since the reasons for doing it in C++ doesn't apply to C#

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea in C++, where at the very least you should use typedef. In C# it doesn't make sense as portability is guaranteed by the underlying platform. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use enums if you need, i usually prefer them than constants.

```
[Flags]
enum FOO_UINT32 : uint
{
    MyFlag1 = 0x00000002u,
    MyFlag2 = 0x80000000u,
    FOO_TRUE = 1,
}

public static class MyFunctions
{
    public static function MyFunction(FOO_UINT32 value);
}


// In your code

MyFunctions.MyFunction(FOO_UINT32.MyFlag1 | FOO_UINT32.MyFlag2);
MyFunctions.MyFunction(0);
MyFunctions.MyFunction(FOO_UINT32.FOO_TRUE);
MyFunctions.MyFunction((FOO_UINT32)0x123456);
```

Plus, it don't allows you to pass integer values without a casting, increasing overall readability and reducing risk of errors.

0 is a special case for enums, so it works.